# Function not getting values?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a tip calculator and it seems to not be getting the values of the text input fields. No console errors are being logged. I think it may be the placement of the function and variable scopes but I don't know. Any help would be lovely. Please run the snippet in fullscreen as it looks very bad at the moment.

```js
// Variables
var tipAmount = document.getElementById("tipAmount").value;
var billAmount = document.getElementById("bill").value;
var numPeople = document.getElementById("people").value;
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var output = document.querySelector("span");
// Value checks
getTip = (cost) =>  {
  
if (billAmount == " " || tipAmount == 0) {
  alert("Please enter values");
}

if (numPeople == " " || numPeople <= 1) {
  numPeople = 1;
}
var cost = billAmount * (tipAmount / 100) * numPeople;
console.log(cost);
//Display the tip

document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = cost;
}
// Calculating Tip on button click

button.onclick = () => {
  getTip();
};

// To hide total tip span on load

document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 40em;
  margin: 5vh;
  width: 20em;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 45px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 4vh;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 150px;
}

select {
  font-size: 25px;
}

button {
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4vh;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Tip Calculator</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="calc">
        <form>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <label for="bill">How much was the bill?</label>
              $
              <input type="text" id="bill" placeholder="Bill Amount" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="tipAmount">How was the Service?</label>
              <select id="tipAmount">
                <option disabled selected value="0">
                  -- Choose an Option --
                </option>
                <option value="5">5% - Terrible</option>
                <option value="10">10% - Bad</option>
                <option value="15">15% - Ok</option>
                <option value="20">20% - Good</option>
                <option value="30">30% - Outstanding</option>
              </select>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="people">How many people?</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="people"
                placeholder="Enter Number of People"
              />
            </li>
            <li><button type="button" value="Calculate" />Calculate</li>
            <div id="totalTip">
              <sup>$</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
              <small id="each">each</small>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're getting the values too soon (on page load). Wait to read the `.value` property until `getTip` is running.

Comment: As above comment @S1njack you need to read the values once the button is clicked, declaring variables before button click is fine but you need to update the current values from the fields, which will be available after clicking your calculate button